# How to disable Jira notifications in GitLab?

Tags: jira, gitlab

I want to disable notifications from Jira, like " user1 mentioned this issue in a commit of user1/portal: 'E-test test commit " . Leave notifications about "merge request" and "merge in master branch". How can this be done?

Comment: can you look if the Service templates (Jira issue tracker) is enable in your Gitlab ?

Comment: Yes, service templates is enabled.